# Как можно реализовать продолжение проигрывания MP3-файла после паузы?

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt, qmediaplayer, qtmultimedia

Сейчас для каждой композиции в списке `self.list` создается две кнопки - `pause_btn` и `play_btn`. 
С первой кнопкой все понятно, она просто ставит воспроизведение на паузу, а вот вторая вызывает вопросы.

Кнопка `play_btn` взаимодействует с методом `play()`, который в качестве аргумента принимает путь к композиции и задает источник звука. 
Если поставить аудио на паузу, а потом нажать кнопку `play_btn`, источник будет задан снова и композиция начнет проигрывание с самого начала, а не с места паузы.

Когда в `self.list` был всего один путь к файлу, проблема решалась достаточно просто:

```
def play(self, song):
    if self.player.isAudioAvailable() == False:
        self.player.setMedia(QtMultimedia.QMediaContent(QtCore.QUrl(song)))
    self.player.play()
```

Тут выполняется проверка на наличие звука в проигрывателе, если его нет, задается источник. Когда появится необходимость проигрывания нескольких композиций, возникнет проблема - при нажатии на кнопку, которая относится к другому аудио-файлу, проверка на наличие звука вернет `True`, из-за чего программа проигнорирует строку, которая задает источник. Т.е. последующие нажатия на кнопки `pause_btn` и `play_btn` будут менять состояние проигрывания только одного файла.

Тогда я подумал, что можно сравнить текущий файл в проигрывателе с тем, что принимает метод `play()`. Я нашел метод `media()`, который возвращает заданный источник. Но попытка вывести этот источник в консоль приводит к следующему: 
`<PyQt5.QtMultimedia.QMediaContent object at 0x000001C8CAC43978>`, 
т.е. метод возвращает экземпляр класса `QMediaContent`. Как я понял, его нельзя будет сравнить со строкой, которую принимает метод `play()`. Да и вообще, этот способ показался мне нерациональным.

Пожалуйста, подскажите, как можно реализовать возможность поставить композицию на паузу, а потом продолжить проигрывание снова, при наличии нескольких аудиофайлов?

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui, QtMultimedia

class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.list = ['1.Papercut.mp3', '13.Numb.mp3']
        #self.list = ['bibi.mp3', 'D:/_Qt/EXE/Mp3/new_build/QThread_mp3/img/zvuki_prirody.mp3']

        self.player = QtMultimedia.QMediaPlayer()
        self.box = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()

        line = 0
        for song in self.list:
            play_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Play', clicked=lambda ch, song=song: self.play(song))
            pause_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Pause', clicked=self.pause)
            label = QtWidgets.QLabel(song)
            self.box.addWidget(play_btn, line, 0)
            self.box.addWidget(pause_btn, line, 1)
            self.box.addWidget(label, line, 2)
            line = line + 1

        self.setLayout(self.box)

    # Воспроизведение
    def play(self, song):

        print(str(self.player.media()))

        self.player.setMedia(QtMultimedia.QMediaContent(QtCore.QUrl(song)))
        self.player.play()

    # Пауза
    def pause(self):
        self.player.pause()

    # Повтор
    def replay(self):
        pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWindow()
    window.setWindowTitle('MP3-player, PyQt5')
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обратите внимание я поменял тип данных `self.list` - теперь это словарь
и отметил строки, которые изменил.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui, QtMultimedia

class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

#        self.list = ['1.Papercut.mp3', '13.Numb.mp3']
#        self.list = ['bibi.mp3', 'D:/_Qt/EXE/Mp3/new_build/QThread_mp3/img/zvuki_prirody.mp3']

        self.list = {
            'bibi.mp3': [], 
            'D:/_Qt/EXE/Mp3/new_build/QThread_mp3/img/zvuki_prirody.mp3': []
        }
        self.song = ''                                                            # +++

        self.player = QtMultimedia.QMediaPlayer()
        self.box = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self)      

        for line, song in enumerate(self.list):                                   # enumerate
            # print(line, song)
            play_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Play', clicked=lambda ch, song=song: self.play(song))

            pause_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Pause', clicked=self.pause, enabled=False) # enabled

            label = QtWidgets.QLabel(song)
            self.box.addWidget(play_btn, line, 0)
            self.box.addWidget(pause_btn, line, 1)
            self.box.addWidget(label, line, 2)

            self.list[song].append(play_btn)                                       # +++
            self.list[song].append(pause_btn)                                      # +++

    # Воспроизведение
    def play(self, song):
        if self.player.isAudioAvailable() == False:
            self.player.setMedia(QtMultimedia.QMediaContent(QtCore.QUrl(song)))
            self.list[song][1].setEnabled(True)                                    # +++
            self.song = song                                                       # +++

# ++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv            
        if self.song == song:
            pass
        else:
            self.player.setMedia(QtMultimedia.QMediaContent(QtCore.QUrl(song)))
            self.list[self.song][1].setEnabled(False)
            self.list[song][1].setEnabled(True)
            self.song = song
# ++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

        self.player.play()

    # Пауза
    def pause(self):
        self.player.pause()

    # Повтор
    def replay(self):
        pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWindow()
    window.setWindowTitle('MP3-player, PyQt5')
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное, сейчас буду разбирать:)

Comment: Кстати, когда вы в предыдущем вопросе починили мой код, после `lambda` в строке `play_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Play', clicked=lambda ch, song=song: self.play(song))` появился еще один аргумент - **ch**. Я пытался придумать, как это загуглить, но никак не соображу корректную формулировку.  Если будет время, пожалуйста, расскажите немного о предназначении этого аргумента, т.к. нигде в коде я его больше не видел

Comment: @MAXIM045  `ch` от слова   `checked`, читать здесь https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractbutton.html#clicked

Comment: Спасибо большое:)